# Reaction Rate for Surface Reactions

Tags: surface-chemistry

Assume reactions S1 to S4 in the image. How can I can determine the reaction rate in mol/m2.s with the given Arrhenius parameters?

Cs' and Cs-H are site species on the surface.

Cs' is just an abbreviation for carbon site and unoccupied by hydrogen.
Cs-H is hydrogen occupied carbon site.

For ease of calculation assume an arbitrary site concentration of site species in mol/m2 and the gas species in mol/m3.

[image: Surface Mechanism]

Comment: Note that using photos/screenshots of text instead of typing text itself is highly discouraged.  The image text content cannot be indexed nor searched for, nor can be reused in answers.  Specifically handwritten scripts can be difficult to decipher.  Consider  copy/pasting or rewriting of at least essential parts. 
// Optionally, here are formatting guides for [texts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) and [formulas/equations/expressions](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here).

Comment: @Poutnik well it is neither of the above rest assured. This part of a larger project and as a mechanical engineer my chemical background is very limited.

Comment: @Poutnik I just asked a question nothing weird about it. Do I really need to explain the background of why I need to ask? Feel free to remove the question if you want.

Comment: It is OK for me. Knowledge of background and purpose generally helps to formulate optimal answers, as what is needed sometimes differs from what is asked.

Comment: Well I'm modelling the thermal decomposition of methane in a software called ANSYS Fluent. I modelled the homogeneous decomposition using a 37 step process but struggling with the surface reactions. The software doesn't have capability of performing surface reactions efficiently so I need to code those in and to do that I need some basic understanding about the mechanism which is represented in S1 to S4.

Comment: S1 - S4 occur due to autocatalysis from the nucleated carbon a product of the reaction itself.

Comment: Just technical note: Elaboration of the question and adding details is better to add to the question itself than to post as comments, that have temporal nature. Comments may be moved to site chat rooms or deleted if not relevant anymore. (I also deleted few my obsokete comments).

Comment: @Poutnik I didn't get the time to edit my post due to time difference. If I edit it now, would the question open again?

Comment: After editing, you have to ask for reopening. If mods or enough of users with close/reopen voting privilege consider it worthy, it will be reopened.

Answer (score 1):

> [OP] For ease of calculation assume an arbitrary site concentration of site species in $\pu{mol/m2}$ and the gas species in $\pu{mol/m3}$.

Although this may seem OK, in the theory of heterogeneous-catalyzed chemical reactions, that unit for concentration is not frequently employed. Typically those magnitudes are measured in terms of fractions $\theta_j$. I you have ever seen the BET's derivation or Langmuir's theory, the balances of sites are treated in fractions, not concentrations over a surface.

> [OP] How can I can determine the reaction rate in $\pu{mol/m-2s-1}$ with the given Arrhenius parameters?

This is an irritating fact when publishers don't specify in a precise manner the volume or surface in question, which the kinetic rate constants are referred too. This happens too frequently. I will give you a bunch of definitions of rate of reactions:

- Rate of reaction based on **reacting fluid volume** $V$
  $$ r_i = \frac{1}{V} \frac{\mathrm{d}N_i}{\mathrm{d}t} \tag{1} $$
- Rate of reaction based on the **mass of solid** $W$, really used in fluid-solid systems, when we have a mass of catalyst $W$
  $$ r_i' = \frac{1}{W} \frac{\mathrm{d}N_i}{\mathrm{d}t} \tag{2} $$
- Rate of reaction based on the **interface of a gas-solid system** $S$
  $$ r_i'' = \frac{1}{S} \frac{\mathrm{d}N_i}{\mathrm{d}t} \tag{3} $$
- Rate of reaction based on the **volume of solid** $V_s$ in gas-solid reacting systems
  $$ r_i''' = \frac{1}{V_s} \frac{\mathrm{d}N_i}{\mathrm{d}t} \tag{4} $$
- Rate of reaction based on the **volume of the reactor** $V_r$, *not* to be confused to the volume of the fluid phase. This one is rarely used
  $$ r_i'''' = \frac{1}{V_r} \frac{\mathrm{d}N_i}{\mathrm{d}t} \tag{5} $$

In my opinion, they gave you the rate in the form of Eq. (4), but you want it in terms of Eq. (3), thus we need two pieces of information:

1. The surface area of the catalyst per unit mass of catalyst $S_\mathrm{a}$. This can be obtained experimentally by the $\ce{N2}$ test.
2. The mass density of the catalyst $\rho_\mathrm{c}$, which if you know its nature, I am sure you can find it everywhere.

Once you write every rate of reaction, where the concentrations are divided by the standard concentration, you will end with the rate law in the fashion $ r = k \cdot [...] $, where $k$ has units of $r$. The relationship we need finally is

$$ k''' = (S_\mathrm{a} \rho_\mathrm{c})k'' \tag{6} $$

$$ \pu{\frac{\pu{mol}}{\pu{m3 cat· s}}} =
   \left[{\frac{\pu{m2 cat}}{\pu{kg cat}}}\right]
   \left[{\frac{\pu{kg cat}}{\pu{m3 cat}}}\right]
   \left[\pu{\frac{\pu{mol}}{\pu{m2 cat · s}}}\right] \tag{7}$$

Comment: your answer is the most helpful I got from everyone I asked so far. I would have liked to discuss more but the question was closed during the night and I didn't have time to edit it. Is it possible to take our discussion to a previous post which you commented on that includes the same question? I will edit that one instead with the additional info and code. Your help will greatly appreciated.

Comment: @Rayana Hello Rayana. Yes, I remember your post, I have been so busy lately... Of course I'd help you. Maybe you can open a chat room?

Comment: Thanks for your time. At the moment I'm trying to edit the last post to try include as much information as possible with my findings. I didn't think not including them would be an issue because the data is just too much. I will try my best to consolidate. It seems you were able to capture what I was looking for with limited info which quite impressive. I think you might have the answer once all the info is provided to you. I don't have the 'create a new room' option in the chat page. Not sure why. Will try again once I finish editing the post.

Comment: @Rayana I am flattered. Ping me when you are done.

Comment: I have edited with old post and added additional details. Looking forward to discuss.